# Is there a test version of the NPM repository, akin to PyPI's test.pypi.org?

Tags: npm

I am just getting into developing an NPM package and couldn't find a testing package repository similar to what PyPI has. As this is so useful when developing Python packages, I'd find it surprising if NPM simply lacks an equivalent.

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same question and it looks like we don't that even in 2024